# Using values from one CSV against all values of a different CSV jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I need to send post calls in jmeter and have two sets of variables (store(x) and product(y)). I only have a couple stores and want to run all product through each store. Right now they are stored as two different files. When I run my test right now it picks up Store 1 product 1.. Store 2 product 2 then Store 1 product 3 I would like it to run Store (1) product (1), store (1) product (2) then store (2) product (1).  What functionality can i use to run through all combinations of store (1) and products (y) before moving onto store 2 to and products (y)

| Store | Product |
| --- | --- |
| store1 | prod1 |
| store2 | prod2 |
|  | prod3 |
|  | prod4 |

- **Right now I get**

(store1, prod1,

Strore2, prod2

Store1, prod3

Store,2 prod4)

- **What I want is**

(store1, prod1

store1, prod2

store1, prod3

store1, prod4

store2, prod1

store2, prod2

store2, prod3

store2, prod4)

Answer (score 0):

I would go for [Loop Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller), the "Loop Count" can be set to the number of lines in the `products.csv` file dynamically via [__groovy() function](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy) like:

```
${__groovy(new File('products.csv').readLines().size(),)}
```

Demo:

[image]